# Returning a element's id using its name with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm making a custom jQuery validation method:

```
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("workaround", function(input, element) {
            if (!($(/*asdf*/).hasClass("intra-field-label"))) 
            {
                return true;
            } 
        }, "This is required");
```

`input` is the 'name' of the element. I am trying to get the 'id' of the element, or if I can simply check for the presence of a class using only a 'name', then I want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("workaround", function(input, element) {
        if (!($("input[name=" + input + "]").hasClass("intra-field-label"))) 
        {
            return true;
        } 
    }, "This is required");
```

**Considering that your element will always be an** `<input />`.

**Otherwise change to** `$("[name=" + input + "]")`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't think the first argument, `input`, is the **name** of the element. It should be the **value** the input currently holds, according to the example given in [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod).

The second argument is the element that is being validated. Therefore you can simply check:

```
if ($(element).hasClass('intra-field-label'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Box9 is correct, the first parameter is the value, the second is the element containing the value.  As you know you can also get the value by element.value

```
 $.validator.addMethod("ValidateAdUser", function (value, element)
        {
        }
```